# How do you get 1 record per group in MySQL when dates match?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This is not a duplicate as far as I can tell as the others all have DIFFERENT dates. As an example, I have the following table of company, meter, and last date serviced:

```
Company    MeterCode  Name  LastDate
A          1          MeA   1/1/20
A          2          MeB   1/1/20
A          3          MeC   1/2/20
A          4          MeD   1/2/20

B          1          MeE   2/1/20
B          2          MeF   2/1/20
B          3          MeG   2/2/20
B          4          MeH   2/2/20
```

How do I query this table to get 1 row per company returning all columns but with the most recent date? Multiple meters can have the same last serviced date as you see but I don't care which meter I end up with as long as it's the most recent date. In the example above I'd want to end up with something like:

```
Company    MeterCode  Name  LastDate
A          4          MeD   1/2/20
B          4          MeH   2/2/20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql versions prior to 8.0+ you can use a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.metercode = (
  select metercode from tablename
  where company = t.company
  order by lastdate desc, metercode desc limit 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sGU8MwgpEWZBR3i7iuQT7m/0).
Results:

```
| Company | MeterCode | Name | LastDate  |
| ------- | --------- | ---- | ----------|
| A       | 4         | MeD  | 01/02/20  |
| B       | 4         | MeH  | 02/02/20  |
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! However, it's apparently inefficient and takes a long time (6s or so per run) so I ended up returning all meters that fit a criteria, add 1 record per company to an array and return that array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query that is asked frequently on Stack Overflow.

Here's a solution that works in MySQL 8.0, which supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html):

```
SELECT t.Company, t.MeterCode, t.Name, t.LastDate
FROM (
    SELECT Company, MeterCode, Name, LastDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY LastDate DESC) AS rownum
    FROM WhateverYourTableNameIs
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum = 1
```

You may ask, "what if I'm not using MySQL 8.0?"

MySQL 8.0 has now been in GA release for two years. I think it's time to start telling people they should upgrade if they want the features it supports.